# Can't get locales to work properly

Tags: localization

So I've setup locales following the [official guide](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/localization-guide) and am going with the option where English (en_gb) is the default and Danish (da_dk) is in a sub-folder:

http://mysite.com      --> en default
http://mysite.com/dk/  --> dk sub-folder

In summary, I've set the locales in Settings -> Locales

[image]

I've enabled them for my section (which is a channel):

[image]

I've set the siteURL array (single domain config):

```
'siteUrl' => array(
    'en' => 'http://mysite.com',
    'dk' => 'http://mysite.com/dk/',
),
```

I've created the folder structure and copied the index.php file and .htaccess file across to the `dk/` folder:

```
craft/
public_html/            --> mysite.com/
    .htaccess
    index.php
    dk/                 --> mysite.com/dk/
        .htaccess
        index.php
```

And I've made the edit to the `dk/index.php` file:

```
// Path to your craft/ folder
$craftPath = '../../craft';

// Tell Craft to serve the Danish content
define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'dk');
```

Viewing my entry in English works fine:

```
http://mysite.com/segment/title  --> Shows in English
```

Viewing the same entry in Danish directs to:

```
http://mysite.com/danishsegment/title --> Missing /dk/ in URL. Nothing shown
```

So the preview link for Denmark doesn't include the country segment in the URL (`dk/`) and results in a 404. Even manually adding `dk/` to the URL results in a 404. It doesn't seem to be recognising the Danish locale at all.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Here are the contents of my .htaccess files. All standard Craft with a Type to ensure PHP 5.6 is used:

```
AddType x-httpd-php56 .php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The 'Offers' section (Channel) is set to have a different URL for each Locale:

[image]

Comment: Is there a RewriteBase in the `.htaccess` in the Danish locale directory?

Comment: No RewriteBase in any .htaccess file. I looked for that originally in case that was causing the problem. I've updated my question with the contents of my .htaccess file for reference.

Comment: What is AllowOverride set to?

Comment: In php.ini? I don't have access to the php.ini file directly but it is set to true. I have lots of other sites setup and working with custom .htaccess files. Even with Craft it's all been working fine. It's just now I'm adding in locales that for some reason it doesn't seem to want to add the `/dk/` segment to the URL - even when clicking on the link in the Entries panel of Craft. It doesn't include the `/dk/` part in the URL and adding it results in a 404. `http://mysite.com/dk/` shows the index page but the custom Section URL for Denmark is added or apparently working.

Comment: Granted I have all the config in `/etc/httpd/vhosts/hostname.conf`, but I do have the locale prepended in the rewrite for the one multilocale site I have running:

`RewriteRule (.+) /en/index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: I've just given that a try in `/dk/.htaccess`, changing the RewriteRule to `RewriteRule (.+) /dk/index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]` but still no dice. It's weird that in the Entries listing Under Danish the links to the individual entries in that channel link off to the site *without* `/dk/` in them. I'd have expected this to be wired in. Even adding it manually then returns a 404 but the `/dk/index.php` displays fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting `da_dk` in as the key in the siteUrl array?

Comment: Closer! That solves half of the problem. The links in the Entries listing now correctly link to `mysite.com/dk/tilbud-og-kampagner/{title}`. The trouble is that it still results in a 404. `mysite.com/dk/` correctly shows the index page. It seems like it's so close.

Comment: And you obviously removed the `dk` part in the rewriterule?

Comment: Yep, that's back to `RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]`.

Comment: Oddly the live preview for the Danish version of the entry works fine. It's just the actual page URL itself which doesn't resolve.

Comment: Maybe you need to do `define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'da_dk');` as well?

Comment: Eureka! It finally works! The combination of using `da_dk` in the siteURL array and `define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'da_dk');` in `/dk/index.php` got things resolving correctly. I can't thank you enough. That's had me stumped all afternoon.

Comment: Glad to be able to help!